# Render ModelForm with ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a questionnaire model with a many-to-many relationship with a question model. The idea is that you can dynamically add questions to a questionnaire.

I want o make a ModelForm which displays all the questions assigned to a particular questionnaire, with inputs for the answers, and not a ChoiceField to select questions. Is this possible?

My models are as such:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    answer = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=200)
    questions = model.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

Thank you